# rubygems setup.rb: no such file of directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a small question. When I tried to install rubygems by following the code here:

```
wget 'http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz'

tar -vxzf rubygems-1.3.5.tgz

cd rubygems-1.3.5

ruby setup.rb
```

But when I try to do `ruby setup.rb` it says `bash: /usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
.`
So I tried `which ruby` and it says `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Any ideas how I can fix this path thing?

Answer (score 0):

i got this to work,i had to update my path on /root and /home for this to work.

`vim .bash_profile` *in root and home*
replace `PATH` with 
`PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`

and it's working now